# Promise возвращает статус pending в теле .done()

Tags: javascript

Привет. Почему Promise возвращает undefined, а в своём теле уже показывает resolved и value? И как можно достать то, что лежит в [[PromiseValue]]

```
function searchForPopulars(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/engine/functions.php?action=findPopularDirection',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        })
        .done(json => resolve(json))
        .fail(() => reject('An error occured: Populars not parsed'));
    });
}

let populars = searchForPopulars();
console.log(populars);
```

Изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему дубликат, если вопрос скорее по спецификации `promise`?

Comment: @ThisMan, потому что проблема не в Promise, а в том, как его отображает консоль в хроме. Собственно на картинке хорошо видно: первый вывод - pending, раскрыв - resolved

Comment: @Grundy а парсить [[PromiseValue]] как?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, никак, это внутренний слот. он тебе не нужен. Добавляешь обработчик `then` и в коллбэке для success тебе придет результат в качестве параметра. Подробнее рассмотрено в вопросе: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/186999)